# Formatting a column with pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

The `Difference` column of the pandas datasheet prints out the list for the rows for multiple values for the columns how would I be able to set it so that it prints all the numbers just once as shown in the Expected output?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

a = np.array([12,12,12,9,43,43,43,22,8,9,9,43])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': a})

(df.groupby('Value', as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'Repetition Count': ('Value', 'size'), 
           'Percent(%)': ('Value', lambda x: round(x.size/len(a) *100, 2)),
           'Difference(%)': ('Value', lambda x: round((x-10)/10 *100, 2))})
)
```

Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

```
Difference
-20.0
-10.0
20.0
120.0
330.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x.iloc[0]` instead of `x`:

```
a = np.array([12,12,12,9,43,43,43,22,8,9,9,43])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': a})

(df.groupby('Value', as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'Repetition Count': ('Value', 'size'), 
           'Percent(%)': ('Value', lambda x: round(x.size/len(a) *100, 2)),
           'Difference(%)': ('Value', lambda x: round((x.iloc[0]-10)/10 *100, 2))})
)
```

As you are grouping by `Value`, the values of `Value` in the series during the aggregation will be the same.  Hence, you can just take one of them if you don't want all (same) values of `Value` listed.

**Result:**

```
   Value  Repetition Count  Percent(%)  Difference(%)
0      8                 1        8.33          -20.0
1      9                 3       25.00          -10.0
2     12                 3       25.00           20.0
3     22                 1        8.33          120.0
4     43                 4       33.33          330.0
```